# Tratar elementos do POST no Django Rest Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Boa noite,

Possuo um Model com:

```
camid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Um serializer:

```
class CameraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Camera
        fields = ["camid", "nome", "path", "tipo", "function"]
```

E uma view:

```
class CameraList(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = CameraSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                host = HostsZm.objects.order_by('qusado')[0:1].get()
                if host.qusado < host.qtotal:

                    nome = request.data['nome']
                    path = request.data['path']
                    tipo = request.data['tipo']
                    function = request.data['function']

                    serializer.save(user=self.request.user, host=host.host)

                    zm.add_camwzone("id adicionado via post", nome, "", path, tipo, function, host.host)
                    host.qusado += 1
                    host.save()          
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception:
            return JsonResponse({'Erro:': "Ocorreu um erro no servidor (CLP)"},status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

**Meu problema:**

Preciso enviar os dados inseridos pelo usuário utilizando o POST. E enviá-los para a função "add_camwzone" no arquivo "zm", que irá enviar os dados para uma API de terceiro. Consigo tratar os dados do POST através do "request.data[field]".

Porém, além dos dados enviados pelo usuário, eu preciso receber também o ID (camid do Model) dos valores que foram enviados pelo cliente via POST.

Já o campo "camid" é gerado automaticamente, não consigo pegar o valor através do request.data.

Como eu posso fazer para resgatar esse valor "camid"?

Exemplo de uma requisição no Postman que retorna o ID:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde esta a "função `add_camwzone`"? Falta alguma coisa nessa view ou está completa?

Comment: Voce pode receber os dados do metodo save, atribuindo o metodo a uma variavel. exemplo: valor_camid = serializer.save(user=self.request.user, host=host.host) zm.add_camwzone(valor_camid.camid, nome, "", path, tipo, function, host.host)